# for the function max3bad..provide an input which will produce wrong output

Tags: python-3.x

[provide an input which will produce wrong output.Here is an function to return the maximum value among three positive integers. There is an error in this function. Provide an input triple (n1,n2,n3), where n1, n2 and n3 are all positive integers, for which max3bad produces an incorrect output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7km12.png)

Answer (score 0):

This program checks for the value of comparision of the values in first if statement x is compared with y and z then in second if statement y is compared with z and not x the else max is assigned to z...

BUT THIS PROGRAM GIVES A WRONG OUTPUT FOR AN INPUT OF ----
(2,1,4)